# A detail missing in this proof of this Löwenheim–Skolem theorem?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This proof is found on p. 112 of Wolfgang Rautenberg's *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition).

[image]

The detail that bugs me here is that it is nowhere mentioned that $\mathcal{L}$ is countable; I've checked that the proof succeeds if it is. On the contrary, if $\mathcal{L}$ is uncountable, $\text{Var} \times \mathcal{L}$ is uncountable as well, hence $C$ is uncountable and the proof fails.

I tried to fix it. Let $T \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ be a consistent countable theory and let $\mathcal{L}$ be uncountable. Since $T$ is countable, its formulas contain countably many constant symbols, function symbols and predicate symbols. Therefore, there exists a language with this countable *signature* (i.e., the set of constant symbols, function symbols and predicate symbols) $\mathcal{L}^{-} \supseteq T$ which is countable, since any language with a countable signature is countable. We can thus run the original proof with $\mathcal{L}^-$ successfully.

I would like to know whether my fix succeeds and whether the author really overlooked this detail or I'm just missing something. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: As your 'fix' shows, the result holds no matter whether the original language is uncountable or countable, since what only matters for models of the theory is the sublanguage determined by the non-logical symbols of the theory.  So, your point is entirely right, but it is not common to address such issues in logical proofs. But since this a textbook, Rautenberg should have added,that, without loss of generality, the language may be assumed to be countable.

Nevertheless, Rautenberg's proof looks a bit roundabout, much more cumbersome than in his German textbook.

Comment: @sequitur Thank you for the comment! Up to this point in the book, Rautenberg has been very precise, and I congratulate him for that. But I agree that if there's going to be a Fourth Edition of the book, this detail should be added or at least mentioned.